# Prove that H:={z∈C×: z^n= 1 for some n∈Z+} ≤C^(×) .(Note: Different values of z can use different values of n; i.e. n is not fixed.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a three part question in which I completed the first part, an am confused on notation on the second, and the third I am also confused on notation. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

1)Completed: Let G be a group and let Hi, i ∈ I be a collection of
subgroups of G.
Then the intersection
H =

i∈I
Hi
,
is a subgroup of G
.... For This one I stated that H is nonempty, identity belongs to every H. Suppose a and b are in H which implies that a and b are in H. for all i in ba contained to Hi for all i. As Hi is closed under products then that implies ab is contained in H.

2. Prove that H:={z∈C×: z^n= 1 for some n∈Z+} ≤C^(×) .(Note:  Different values of z can use different values of n; i.e. n is not fixed.
   This one I'm confused on the notation. C^x is complex numbers minus 0? Also I think starting these proofs are the hardest part.
3. Let H:={A∈GLn(R) :AtA=I}, where At denotes the transpose of matrix A.  Prove that H≤GLn(R).

On this one I don't understand the notation GLn(R). Also, I need to freshen up on transposing matrices. I know that this can be done similarly to the shoes-socks property of inverses

Comment: You should learn (and use) MathJax. Not hard, and the results are lovely. That $\mathrm{GL}_n(\Bbb R)$ you ask about is the set of nonsingular $n$-by-$n$ real matrices.

Comment: Thanks, and I will. Seems so much easier than trying to type everything with normal font